# Load php extensions in google app engine production environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Is it possible to load php extensions not loaded by default in a google app engine production environment ?

Here is my app : http://hellokatest.appspot.com

I would like to load `imap.so` extension.

Comment: As far as i know. Adding extensions is not possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot.

If there are extensions missing, you can add a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request) and we'll see what we can do about adding it.